# como puedo solucionar este error Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html5, php5

Estimado presento un error. cuando yo ejecuto este pequeño blog en **mi computadora localmente con xampp y en el navegador no presento este error con el session_start** pero ahora que subi a un hosting gratuito como es 000web me lanza este error, **no se si tiene que ver con el hosting porque localmete no presenta este bug**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**este es mi file conexion.php, es la coneccion ala base de dato con ello no tengo ningun problema ya que puedo guardar y consultar pero al realizar una sesion no puedo acceder dedido aque no se crea la variable de session**

```
<?php
$host="127.0.0.1";
$user="root";
$password="xxxxxx";
$dbname="inicio";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());
  /* Iniciar sesión ---  registro.php -- redireccion.php linea*/
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
?>
```

**desde este archivo realizo el llamado del file conexion.php** con el

```
<?php require_once 'conexion.php';?>
<?php  require_once 'helper.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Blog</title>

   <!--style-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="inicio.css">

   <!--boostrap-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <!--fontaawesome-->
   <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.0/js/all.js"
      integrity="sha384-ukiibbYjFS/1dhODSWD+PrZ6+CGCgf8VbyUH7bQQNUulL+2r59uGYToovytTf4Xm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>
</head>

<body>

   <div class="container contenedor">

   <!--header pagina-->
   <header id="" class="text-center">

      <h1 class = "logo">
         BLog Eliexer Urbina.
      </h1>

   </header>

   <!--navbar-->
   <nav id="menu">
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
         </li>

            <?php 
               // function ubicada en helper.php con parametro de variable $con conexion.php
               // function recibe todos los campos de la tabla categorias
                    $categorias = conseguirCategorias($con);
                    if(!empty($categorias)):
                    while($category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categorias)): 
                ?>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <!--realiza enlace hacia el archivo con la url categoria.php?id= -->
                     <a class="nav-link" href="categoria.php?id=<?=$category['id']?>">
                     <?=$category['nombre']?>
                     </a>
                  </li>
            <?php 
               endwhile;
               endif;
                ?>
         
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactos</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>

   <div class="contenedor">
```

**archivo donde reacibe los datos para abrir una sesion**

```
<?php
   
// Iniciar la sesión y la conexión a bd
require_once '../include/conexion.php';
// Recoger datos del formulario
if(isset($_POST)){ 
   
   // Recoger datos del formulario
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
   $password = $_POST['pass'];

   // Consulta para comprobar las credenciales del usuario
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";
   $login = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   //var_dump($login);

   if($login && mysqli_num_rows($login) == 1){

      // $usuario = todo los registros que contiene la consulta 
      $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login); 
      //var_dump($usuario);
    
      // Comprobar la contraseña del usuario true/false
      $verify = password_verify($password, $usuario['pasword']);
      //var_dump($verify);

      if($verify){
            // Utilizar una sesión para guardar los datos del usuario logueado
         $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

         //var_dump($_SESSION['usuario']);
         //die();
        }else{

            // Si algo falla enviar una sesión con la fallo
            $_SESSION['error_login'] = "Login incorrectooo!!";
         //var_dump($_SESSION['error_login']);
      
      }
   } else{
      // mensaje de error
      $_SESSION['error_login'] = "Login incorrectoxxx!!";
      //var_dump($_SESSION['error_login']);
     
   }  
};
// Redirigir al inicio.php
header('Location: ../index.php');
?>
```

Comment: El error es claro en la linea 3 del archivo `conexion.php` se está emitiendo un caracter.
El password tiene los caracteres `?>`?
Si lo tiene tenés que separarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que session_start() no es para indicar que ahi es cuando tiene que iniciar la sesión.

session_start() tiene que ir arriba del todo ya que le estás indicando al servidor que se ejecutaran sesiones en este documento de php.

Cuando haces el isset de la sessión, nunca te podrá responder ya que para ver si hay una iniciada o no, primero tienes que haber cargado el session_start(), de lo contrario php no podra comprobar el if(!isset($_SESSION))

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```